# Can you change your boost mid-game?

Tags: titanfall-2

I like to play all the game modes in Titanfall, and therefore have a setup of pilot boost and titan for each mode. Changing pilot loadout and wich titan I am using is easy, but I often join games a little after they start and have no way to change what boost I have selected. For example, I had just played capture the flag match and had the pilot sentry boost, then I played a bounty hunt game where I like to use the smart pistol boost (I know, what a tryhard), but could not switch to it. Is there any way to switch boosts other than when the game starts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, you can't change your boost mid-match. You have to do it between matches. This is likely because different boosts take different amounts of time to charge. This is likely to avoid people manipulating it to get better boosts faster. This is why I used to use Dice Roll.(But then I changed to Smart Pistol).